# Python Websockets connections refused Bad Checksum

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket

We have an ethernet RFID reader and a test program that allows us to communicate with the device trough websockets. The test program is probably written in C#. The python script i'm trying to write to communicate with the device however is not working. 
the code looks like :

```
import websocket
import thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def test(ws):
    ws.send("<command><heartbeat/></command>")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://192.168.0.194:10001",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = test
    ws.run_forever()
```

When i use a network sniffer i can clearly see multiple lines of back and forth communication between python and the reader but the reader is closing the connection.

The only feedback im getting is an error code with the following description:

```
Error when receiving the TCP channel
• Connection was aborted
• TCP/IP protocol error
• Permissible number of connections at one port was exceeded
• Check socket programming on the user side or find the fault with network analyzer
(Wireshark).
```

And with the network sniffer i can see all my messages have a bad checksum like:

```
Checksum: 0xcc83 (incorrect, should be 0xb8ad)
```

Comment: Is the error in the c# part of this pair?

Comment: The C# program works just fine, and when i use the network sniffer it it has the correct checksum. I'm basicly trying to recreate a program that can be embedded into our system.

Comment: Maybe using another protocol ? A lot reader and protocols. which one ? Checksum: `Maybe serial over ethernet !`

Comment: Could it be that you have another connection active to the reader, but the reader only allows a single connection? `Permissible number of connections at one port was exceeded` seems to indicate that.

Comment: Have you tried a different websockets implementation? Maybe https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server

Comment: Barny i'm going to try that next week i don't have the time at hand right now :(